# jquery: mouseover works, but click wont' work

Tags: jquery, events

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script>
$("#test").live("click", function(){
    alert('');          
});
$("#tbl").live("mouseover",function(){
    $("#title").html('<input id="test" type="button" value="test button" />');
});
$("#tbl").live("mouseleave",function(){
    $("#title").html('');
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id='tbl' width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="title">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="content">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

$("#test").live("click"...)  doesn't work, but if I change to mouseover it works.
Any one can help?

Thanks,
Cheng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using mouseover instead of mouseenter. I have a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GY7dj/9/).

Comment: Yeah the mouseover event was firing every time you moved or clicked the mouse which was causing the button to be replaced over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mouseenter` instessd of `mouseover`,and as @davecoulter said put ";" end of the statments,

```
  $("#test").live("click", function(){
        alert();
    });
    $("#tbl").live("mouseenter",function(){
        $("#title").html('<input id="test" type="button" value="test button" />');
    });
    $("#tbl").live("mouseleave",function(){
        $("#title").html('');
    });
```

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z2ZYs/1/

Comment: And change `alert();` to `alert('');`!

Comment: it is worrking with me without it,but it will say undifined

Answer (score 0):

Cheng:

Just a stab, but try putting ';' at the ends of your statements:

```
$("#test").live("click", function(){
    alert();
});
$("#tbl").live("mouseover",function(){
    $("#title").html('<input id="test" type="button" value="test button" />');
});
$("#tbl").live("mouseleave",function(){
    $("#title").html('');
});
```

Comment: You don't need semi-colons in certain circumstances (such as one-line functions), and this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `alert()`  does not work like this . just do this `alert('');`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put a string in the `alert('Something')` statement.

I have a working example [**here (jsFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/alr3/Eq2Re/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try replace alert() to alert("Anything");
It's just work fine on my computer.